# Network problem in Ubuntu 20.04 on NUC8i5BEK but not under PoP_OS! 20.04

Tags: networking, ethernet

I really prefer running Ubuntu over PoP_OS! but Im haunted by network issues. Running ubuntu 18.04 gives me network on my machine (but that means that I cannot install software that needs a new version av glib-c). Upgrading to ubuntu 20.04 gives me no network what so ever, no ethernet and no wifi. Then I tried PoP_OS 20.04 and to my surprise everytning works out of the box. So what can I do to have Ubuntu 20.04 installed and still have the networking that PoP_OS provides? What is the difference between the distros?

Comment: I don't believe there is any appreciable difference as it pertains to the ability to connect to a network, but you haven't given us much to go on.  Your question implies that you are installing 18.04 and upgrading to 20.04 - if you're doing this - you should just install 20.04.1 directly. If you'd like assistance with Ubuntu, please tell us **exactly** the steps you are taking when you try to connect to a network and tell us **exactly** what happens.

Comment: We need more information. We expect details from you, if it wifi didn't work what did you try or what actions did you take to troubleshoot issue ?

Comment: I have some updates. I think the problem is in Gnome. I got tired of troubleshooting without internet [it's hard] and installed Kubuntu - and everything worked out of the box. Before that I used TeeJee's Ukuu to try different kernels and that did not solve my problems. So if things work on the same distro, the same kernel but with another dm I guess the problem boils down to Gnome. 
If anyone knows how to get things running under Gnome I would appreciate a hint.